# Javascript - Load div and content on hover

Tags: javascript

I got a little problem.
I have to load content in a div, when the user hover over a div.

```
<div id="table">
<div class="hoverover">
    <!--<img src="ImageLink">-->
    Image goes here.
</div>
</div>
```

The div "table" is where the users mouse have to be to show the second div.
The div "hoverover" must only be loaded if the users mouse is in the div "table". So any pictures in the div "hoverover" is not loaded before the users mouse is in "table".

I have been looking at this, but it's not what I was searing for.
jsfiddle.net/LD8t6/ and this http://jsfiddle.net/ujBZY/9/ (Am I stupid or.. since I can not get this to work?)

I have made a fiddle of my progress here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zwipper/xCmxj/

If I have overlooked a thread on this topic, I am sorry. I may have seen me blind to this in my search.

I have a little problem to get a javascript to load the div "hoverover" properly. 
Can any of you get a javascript to work? It will be a great help :)

I hope this is enough info, this is my first fiddle. If not, please write :)

Thanks :)

Comment: Seems to work. What is it doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GgRmp/)

```
$('#table').hover(
    function(){$('div.hoverover').show('slow'); },

    function(){$('div.hoverover').hide('slow');}
);
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough.
I do NOT want it to load the div called "hoverover" until the mouse is in "table".
What I mean is that there will be some pictures that should not be loaded until the user has mouse in "table".

"hoverover" will be shown about 150 times and 150 images if all the images are loaded at once, the site becomes overloaded. Therefore MUST "hoverover" only be loaded if the mouse is in "table".
Are you with?

Comment: the div hoverover is not loaded until your mouse is in the div with id= table , what do you want , i don't understand

Comment: I want to load anything, exempt #hoverover on the site.
So all content is loadet, but not the #hoverover div.

Comment: Man i added images to fiddle , do you run the fiddle ? because what you said works on this fiddle,just run and test

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution with some ajax.
This is what I have found:

```
  <a href="#" class="ajaxtrigger">Load Ajax</a>
    <div id="target"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
   $(".ajaxtrigger").click(function(){

      $("#target").load("load.php #toggle3");   
   });
})
</script>
```

This is the load.php:

```
<?
echo '<div id="#toggle">Toggle 1</div>';
echo '<div id="#toggle2">Toggle 2</div>';
echo '<div id="#toggle3">Toggle 3</div>';
echo '<div id="#toggle4">Toggle 4</div>';
?>
```

This works when I have the files on me laptop and xampp :)